# Stripe's "cancel_at_period_end" equivalent in paypal?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

I implement a subscription site in which the subscriptions plans are monthly.
I use IPN to handle subscription events.
Now, If a recurring payment failed, I will get the relevant event and will cancel the subscription in my side.
But, what should I do when a user cancels his subscription via my site, and he still has time left in his subscription, and I want to cancel the subscription only in the end of the subscription period?
What can I do if the user cancels his subscription via PayPal and still has time left in his subscription?
In stripe you simply set "cancel_at_period_end=true" and then it's the same scenario.

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent, PayPal doesn't keep track of anything for you. You'll receive cancel events whenever a profile is cancelled.

If you want to keep track of paid-through periods, that logic is up to you.

Comment: Thank you! how would you suggest to implement this logic?

Comment: Keep track of when the profile started (datetime) ,whether it's been cancelled (true/false), and when it was cancelled (datetime).  If it's been cancelled, calculate the difference between the date time objects, mod the period_length.  If the (current time - cancelled time) is < the calculation result or >= the period_length, the profile hasn't been paid through. You know, something like that